# Justify buttom not showing in CKEditor 4.6.2

Tags: wysiwyg

I am using CKEditor 4.6.2, Wysiwyg 7.x-2.4 also I have download justify plugin 4.6.2 from https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/justify and added

```
jQuery(function() {
    CKEDITOR.config.extraPlugins = 'justify';
});
```

to ckeditor.js. From the list of Wysiwyg profile, I have selected Align left, Right and Justify but then also Alignment button is missing from Wysiwyg toolbar.

Comment: I can't remember well since I've dabbled with WYSIWYG+CKEditor a long time ago, but from what I remember, you have to write an integration with WYSIWYG module otherwise it won't work.

Comment: see here: https://www.thirdandgrove.com/creating-ckeditor-plugin-drupal-7-wysiwyg for example.